# EF4 STE's and MVC2 - ChangeTracker not POSTing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, self-tracking-entities

I'm trying to set up an MVC2 app with Entity Framework Self-Tracking-Entities.  My view is a strongly-typed view of the entity type generated by the STE T4 template.  Here's my GET:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        var ri = new App1Service.App1Client().GetMyObj(id);
        var changeTracking = ri.ChangeTracker.ChangeTrackingEnabled;  // this shows true
        return View(ri);
    }
```

So far, so good.  When this form POSTs, however, ChangeTracker is null / reset to default values, and thus, the STE seems suddenly to forget that it's supposed to be tracking itself:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(MyObj ri)  
    {
         // MyObj.ChangeTracker.ChangeTrackingEnabled now shows false
         // so the following line doesn't save anything:
         new App1Service.App1Client().SaveMyObj(ri);
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

What's the secret to getting the strongly-typed-view to hang onto (and POST back) the whole STE?  If I have to go and do another read to get original values and then apply changes, that seems to defeat the purpose of self-tracking-entities, doesn't it?

Comment: I'd love to know if you ever found any information on this.  I was never able to see any self-tracking behavior when I tried self-tracking entities.  Very little useful documentation I was able to find on this combination of technologies.

Comment: I was able to get my sample app to work by storing the detached EF object in session after the Edit-GET, and then picking it back up again on the Edit-POST (using that object to apply changes).  This consumes memory on the web server, of course, but avoids the re-read scenario above.